# Can't move cursor to the next line in Assembly Operating System using BIOS interrupts

Tags: assembly, newline, 16-bit, real-mode

I'm making a simple 16-bit real mode operating system and I've written the code below to move the cursor to the next line but it only moves down a line once despite the fact that it is called multiple times with and without other commands in between.

```
nextLine:
    pusha

    mov ah, 0x2

    mov bh, 0
    mov dl, 0               ; move the cursor to the far left of the
                            ; screen
    inc dh                  ; move the cursor onto the next line
    int 0x10                ; call the BIOS interupt to move the cursor

    popa
    ret
```

Comment: have you checked what your `dh` value is in between calls to this? Something else could be resetting dh, dx, edx, etc... in the meantime.

Comment: When you `popa`, doesn't `dh` get "unincremented" for next time?

Comment: @FrankKotler I removed `pusha` and `popa` and now it works perfectly, thank you